# Mongo DB: Get all documents inserted after the last known one

Tags: mongodb

```
> db.events.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c3e09913b2c643f1215"), "context" : "jvc8irfjc9cdnf93", "key" : "value" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c4709913b2c643f1216"), "context" : "jvc8irfjc9cdnf93", "key" : "new value" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c4b09913b2c643f1217"), "context" : "jvc8irfjc9cdnf93", "key" : "newer value" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c4f09913b2c643f1218"), "context" : "jvc8irfjc9cdnf93", "key" : "newest value" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c6309913b2c643f1219"), "context" : "0djd8vcndkfnjhv3", "key" : "value" }
```

is a list of events on a Mongo DB server. The client keeps track of the last event he knows about, for example `50911c4709913b2c643f1216`, the second one.

How to I get all events that have been inserted after this known one? In this case `50911c4b09913b2c643f1217`, `50911c4f09913b2c643f1218` and `50911c6309913b2c643f1219`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing the object ids in increasing order here is because the spec says that
`time|machine|pid|inc` is the format for creating the `ObjectId`.

Notice that there is already a time component in the `ObjectId` , but that is in seconds.
The `Date` type in Mongo is the representation of the number of milliseconds from epoch, which will give you some more precision for figuring out time of insertion.

I think the best way is to use a counter in the form of **[Sequence numbers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers)** if you need absolute precision beyond milli seconds, but if you think that your app is not that write intensive just use the **[Date](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates)** type in the form of an additional key called timestamp.

Answer (score 10):

Since the `ObjectId` by default contains a `inc` and a `timestamp` ( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification ) you can actually use the `ObjectId` to understand insertion time (roughly) via:

```
db.col.find({_id: {$gt: {ObjectId("50911c4709913b2c643f1216")}}});
```

However the `ObjectId` cannot always be extremely reliable especially if, in your app, you create the `ObjectId` a while before insertion and actually one record which you know was created later actually shows (because of its `_id`) as earlier.

For insertions in certain scenarios where you cannot trust the `ObjectId` for insertion timer you can add a `ts` field of a BSON Date type (`ISODate`) and range on that using two queries, one to get the original documents time and then another to get all documents after.

I personally prefer to just go for the second method of using a BSON date type since it is more reliable and flexible.

Comment: Can you help me answering the new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66919206/11878372)?

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, you are using the "built-in" ObjectIDs. [They attempt to be unique, not sequential](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs). You can add a timestamp and or use sequence numbers as the official docs suggest and query based on that attribute.

Once you have added this new attribute, you have to perform two queries. One to get the sequential number or timestamp corresponding to the client specified ID and then another query to get items that are inserted after.

Answer (score 0):

Since ObjectID is based on time like others have already mentioned, we can construct our own time based ObjectID for querying. This should save on indexing space :)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8753670/1008449 for an implementation in Javascript.