# How to find documents behind specified document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection contains News.It's sorted by time,client wants to find documents behind specified document,for example,I have 100 news,client give server newsId:(ObjectId("5cfb2cf0b09cc3001152a909"),it's may be 73 position),client hopes server return 10 news behind this newsId(position is 74~83),how to do it?Not "Pageable",client has no page concept，it's refresh or load by last newsId.
Thank you.

---

According to [Mongo DB: Get all documents inserted after the last known one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13158319/6431509), I use code below:

```
//ArticleRepository
@Query(value = "{$and:[{'related':{$in:?0}},{'_id':{$lte:?1}}]}")
List<Article> loadNews(List<String> coinIds, ObjectId lastId, Pageable pageable);

//Model
List<Article> articles = articleRepository.loadNews(list,new ObjectId(lastId),new PageRequest(0, 7, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id")));
```

this code will found documents which inserted behind lastId document.

Comment: Kindly Post a couple of sample documents from your collection to understand the question

Comment: Hi,I found the solution by this link:https://stackoverflow.com/q/13158319/6431509,sort by ObjectId.