# How to query all documents inserted after a given doc in just One query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Assume I have these docs:

```json
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c3e09913b2c643f1215"), "name" : "x", "time" : 1617131149850 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c4709913b2c643f1216"), "name" : "y", "time" : 1617131149851 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c4b09913b2c643f1217"), "name" : "w", "time" : 1617131149852 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c4f09913b2c643f1218"), "name" : "q", "time" : 1617131149853 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50911c6309913b2c643f1219"), "name" : "z", "time" : 1617131149854 }
```

I want to get all documents with time greater than time of the document with `_id="50911c4b09913b2c643f1217"` (which results to "q" and "z").

How can I make the result with just **One query** not two or more?

for example I don't want to fetch "w" in a **separate** query and then query for docs based on "w" time in another query.

Comment: Use aggregation pipeline, look up the first document by _id, then join the collection on itself using time as condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: {
    $gt: ObjectId("50911c4b09913b2c643f1217")
  }
})
```

Based on your comment one solution is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: null,  data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
  {
    $set: {
      filter: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$data",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", ObjectId("50911c4b09913b2c643f1217") ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: { $gt: [ "$$this.time", "$filter.time" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
])
```

However, if you are in mongoshell, i.e. JavaScript I would simply do this:

```
var t = db.collection.findOne( {_id: ObjectId("50911c4b09913b2c643f1217")} ).time
db.collection.find( {time: {$gt: t}} )
```

Comment: I know the ObjectId specifications. in my case _id is not reliable for sorting. The query I need  involves id and time together but how?

Comment: That might work for this particular document but isn't a general-purpose solution because ids are not guaranteed to be monotonically increasing.