# limit mongo search by age?

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'd like to only get documents that were created in the last 24 hrs, is there a way to limit queries by age?

Can I use the doc ids? a limit query?

Should I add a date field and use min/max?

Some other way?

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Adding a timestamp field with index would be the most straightforward and reliable solution. But if you're letting mongodb server generate object ids for you, then you can use _id field because it has a timestamp in it, and there's already an index.

Comment: can you show me an example of the query?

Comment: Here's an example of querying by date using the ObjectID: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date