# Mongodb: Perform a Date range query from the ObjectId in the mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("50a68673476427844b000001"),
  other fields
}
```

I want to do a range query to find records between two dates.  I know that I can get the date from the ObjectId in the mongo shell var doing this:

```
var aDate = ObjectId().getTimestamp()
```

but there isn't a way (as far as I can figure out at the moment) to create an ObjectId consisting of just the timestamp portion - I think my ideal solution is non-functioning mongo shell code would be:

```
var minDate = ObjectId(new Date("2012-11-10"));
var maxDate = ObjectId(new Date("2012-11-17"));
```

Use the find with the minDate and MaxDate as the range values.

Is there a way to do this in the SHELL - I'm not interested in some of the driver products.

Comment: First 8 bytes of mongoid are timestamp in hexadecimal, so you could create a valid ObjectId with first 8 bytes made from date, and rest just zeros, and then do queries similar to this: `{
 _id: {$gt: ObjectId("5087e5b106cffca815000000")}
}`

Comment: There's a good answer for [Can I query MongoDB ObjectId by date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date) which includes an `objectIdWithTimestamp()` JavaScript function.  You can save this function in your [.mongorc.js](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell#Overview-TheMongoDBInteractiveShell-.mongorc.js) to have it available in your `mongo` shell on startup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I query MongoDB ObjectId by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date)

Answer (score 33):

You can do that in 2 steps:

```
 var objIdMin = ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('1990/10/10'))/1000).toString(16) + "000
0000000000000")
 var objIdMax = ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2011/10/22'))/1000).toString(16) + "000
    0000000000000")
 db.myCollection.find({_id:{$gt: objIdMin, $lt: objIdMax}})
```

or in one step (what is less readable):

```
db.myCollection.find({_id:{$gt: ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('1990/10/10'))/1000).toString(16) + "000
    0000000000000"), $lt: ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2011/10/10'))/1000).toString(16) + "000
    0000000000000")}})
```

Comment: or even better: `function dateFromObj( strDate ) {
    return ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date( strDate ))/1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000")
}`

Answer (score 29):

**using mongo shell:**

you can use the ObjectId.fromDate built in method:

```
db.mycollection.find({_id: {$gt: ObjectId.fromDate( new Date('2017-09-23') ) } });
```

**from Node.js  driver:**

you can use the solution provided by @jksdua [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19138789/7435863) as follows:

```
db.mycollection.find({_id: {$gt: ObjectID.createFromTime( Date.now()/1000 ) } });
```

Comment: Just in case anyone else needs it: The mongosh built into MongoDB Compass appears to just have `ObjectId.createFromTime()`, which makes sense since it's an Electron app and presumably using the Node.js driver.