# How to convert from Timestamp to Mongo ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I know that we can use `getTimestamp()` to retrieve the timestamp from the ObjectId, but is there any way to generate an ObjectId from a timestamp?

More specifically, if I have an input of **month** and **year**, then I want to convert it into **Mongo ObjectID** to query in db, how should I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb: Perform a Date range query from the ObjectId in the mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593896/mongodb-perform-a-date-range-query-from-the-objectid-in-the-mongo-shell)

Comment: No that is a different answer, this is if we want to convert a timestamp to objectID where you want the objectID to contain a certain date/time, not necessarily the current datetime

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this,

```
> ObjectId("5a682326bf8380e6e6584ba5").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2018-01-24T06:09:42Z")
> ObjectId.fromDate(ISODate("2018-01-24T06:09:42Z"))
ObjectId("5a6823260000000000000000")
```

Works from mongo shell.

Comment: never understood why the [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/ObjectId/#methods-and-attributes) don't list the `fromDate` function. thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

If you pass a number to the bson ObjectId constructor it will take that as a timestamp and pass it to the [generate](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/9f4380927254290227cda8d5db3a08809b6ce3d6/lib/objectid.js#L153-L156) method.

You can get a Date from a month and year per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982035/1450420) (months start at zero).

So:

```
timestamp = ~~(new Date(2016, 11, 17) / 1000)
new ObjectId(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
dummy_id = ObjectId.from_datetime(gen_time)
```

Where gen_time is datetime.

Comment: I think `from_datetime` is PyMongo equivalent, so it won't work in MongoDB shell. the [answer from vkrishna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629868/how-to-convert-from-timestamp-to-mongo-objectid#answer-48589096) mentions the `fromDate` method

Answer (score -3):

An `ObjectId()` is a 12-byte BSON type and consists of:

- The first 4 bytes representing the seconds since the unix epoch
- The next 3 bytes are the machine identifier
- The next 2 bytes consists of process id
- The last 3 bytes are a random counter value

Clearly, you will not be able to create `ObjectId()` only from timestamp.