# javascript create date from year, month, day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a new `date` in `javascript`.

I have `year`, `month` and `day`. Following [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) tutorial, syntax for creating new `date` should be:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

and that is exactly what I am doing:

```
var d = new Date(2016, 12, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This should be december 17th 2016, but in my console output I see:

```
Tue Jan 17 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Months start from 0.
You should use this:
var d = new Date(2016, 11, 17);

Comment: In Javascript Date Object, months are 0 based. So 0 means January, 11 means December.

try
`var d = new Date(2016, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);` It should be fine.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to [MDN - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **month**
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
>   January to 11 for December.

You should subtract 1 from your month:

```
const d = new Date(2016, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: The date constructor doesn't accept full years. If you plug in `2` for the year, you get `1902`.

Comment: That's true, any Year before 100 will be prefixed with 19xx

Comment: I found that you can use `new Date(0).setFullYear(year, month, day)` instead if `year` needs to be a full year

Comment: Is there an underlying reason why the month is zero based (i.e. offset from the start of the year), and the day is not (an offset from the start of the month)?

Comment: Yes. It's some weird heritage from old languages that were used as base for JavaScript. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2552517/3429323

Answer (score 109):

January is month 0. December is month 11.
So this should work:

```
var d = new Date(2016, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Also, you can just simply do:

```
var d = new Date(2016, 11, 17);
```

Comment: why the month is 0 based & year,day not 

Comment: Seems it's just an old tradition that javascript copied from POSIX/Java. https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime   , http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/javadoc/java.util.Date.html#getMonth%28%29

Comment: so confusing, I was wondering my weekOfYear() function returned 5 for January 1st 

Comment: If you've worked with languages where Arrays start from 1 it makes so much more sense 