# Formating date object in angular, how to

Tags: angular, typescript

I got this type of json format after a get request:

```
{
"name" : "cow",
"date" : {
    "year" : 2012,
    "month" : "JANUARY",
    "dayOfMonth" : 1,
    "dayOfWeek" : "FRIDAY",
    "dayOfYear" : 1,
    "monthValue" : 1,
    "hour" : 2,
    "minute" : 2,
    "second" : 0,
    "nano" : 0,
    "chronology" : {
      "id" : "ISO",
      "calendarType" : "iso8601"
    }
  }
....
}
```

How can I convert the above to the following in typescript/angular:

```
{
"name" : "cow",
"date" : "2012-01-01"
}
```

Then store in the below array.

```
//....correctFormat = [];
service.convertStore()
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    // manipulation here

    correctFormat = "holds result"
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript create date from year, month, day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981982/javascript-create-date-from-year-month-day), then [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to each member, assign it to a new object and store it in the array:

```js
const object = {
  "name": "cow",
  "date": {
    "year": 2012,
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "dayOfMonth": 1,
    "dayOfWeek": "FRIDAY",
    "dayOfYear": 1,
    "monthValue": 1,
    "hour": 2,
    "minute": 2,
    "second": 0,
    "nano": 0,
    "chronology": {
      "id": "ISO",
      "calendarType": "iso8601"
    }
  }
}

const d = object.date
correctFormat = [];
correctFormat.push({
  name: object.name,
  date: d.year + '-' + (0 + '' + d.monthValue).slice(-2) + '-' + (0 + '' + d.dayOfMonth).slice(-2)
});

console.log(correctFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class in Angular:

```
export class MyCustomClass {
   name: string;
   date: string;

   constructor(name: string, date: string) {
       this.name = name;
       this.date = string;
   }
}
```

Then in the service invocation should do:

```
service.convertStore()
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    // manipulation here
    const newFormat = new MyCustomClass(data['name'], `${data['date']['year']}-${data['date']['monthValue']}-${data['date']['dayOfMonth']}`
    correctFormat = "holds result"
})
```