# MongoDB Find all documets in a collection that was created 7 days ago based on objectId

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with the following structure.

`{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5cd29db3a113b44030c5905e"),
 "username": "xyz"
}`

I want to get all the usernames whose `_id` corresponds to the timestamp `7` days ago.

I want a mongo query which can do this.

Is it possible to get this just from a query?

Comment: its only possible on mongo 4.0+ and if you hard code the dates other wise you need code involved to understand whats 7 days ago

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46378711/4368485