# mongodb compass query with objectId in date range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to perform a date range query on the `_id` field using compass.
I've tried what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593896/mongodb-perform-a-date-range-query-from-the-objectid-in-the-mongo-shell) with the following filter:

```
{_id: { $gte: ObjectId.fromDate(new Date('2019-01-01')) } }
```

What am I missing? I'd like to get a list of all documents from some date forward (in this example from 1 Jan 2019 to present). Unfortunately there isn't a timestamp in the document fields so I need to extract it from the object id.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pass a date object to the `ObjectId.fromDate`, not a string. Try this:

```
ObjectId.fromDate(new Date('2019-01-01'))
```

This function works only in the shell and doesn't exist in the drivers.

### EDIT after comments:

Here is a solution that works in Compass as well:

```
{ 
    $expr: { 
        $gte: [
            {"$toDate":"$_id"}, 
            ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") 
        ]
    } 
}
```

Keep in mind, however, that it requires a version of `mongo` of **4.0+**. You can checkout [the docs here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/).

Also, checkout this related topic: [Can I query MongoDB ObjectId by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date)

It is not about `Compass`, but it provides solutions for generating the `ObjectId`s from a date without being dependent on `ObjectId.fromDate()`.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question, I didn't realize I had written it wrong. I'm already doing the query with `new Date(...)` but if I'm reading you correctly, this can't be done within compass and has to be from the shell?

Comment: It's actually a peculiar case with Compass. The request works fine in `Robo 3T`, an alternative of Mongo Compass. And Compass should actually use an embedded MongoDB Shell but the request neither fails, nor works. I'm leaving a related topic for generating the ObjectIds by date as an edit to my answer.

Comment: @WilliamBurnham The solution in the edit works for both the shell and the drivers, including Compass and is entirely self-sufficient as it doesn't involve custom functions.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution, maybe not the best but it does the job. Hopefully this can help someone with the same problem if there isn't a cleaner solution.

I converted the date I needed to an ObjectId outside of compass [online here](https://steveridout.com/mongo-object-time/).
Then I wrote the query with that ObjectId:

```
{_id: { $gte: ObjectId(' object id here ') } }
```

As suggested in the comments, see [this related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date). It's not specific to `Compass` but it provides a solution for generating `ObjectId`s from a date without being dependent on `ObjectId.fromDate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this format-

```
{
$gte:ISODate("2020-03-01"),
$lt:ISODate("2021-03-31")
}
```

example->

```
{
type: "test",
status: "Success",
createdTime:{$gte: '2023-05-10'}
}
```