# Find All Objects Created Before Specified Date

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Mongo has a nice feature that tells you when a document was created.

```
ObjectId("53027f0adb97425bbd0cce39").getTimestamp() = ISODate("2014-02-17T21:28:42Z")
```

How would I get about finding all documents that were created before lets say February 10th 2014? Searched around but doesn't seem like this question comes up. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date    :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTION.find({YOUR_DATE_FIELD: { "$lt": ISODate("2014-02-10") }})
```

Guess that you have to make the same as JoJo recommended:

1. Convert a date to an ObjectId
2. Filter ID using $lt and returned ObjectId

Using pymongo you can do something like this:

```
gen_time = datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 10)
dummy_id = ObjectId.from_datetime(gen_time)
result   = collection.find({"_id": {"$lt": dummy_id}})
```

Reference: http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html

Comment: The Pymongo example is perfect. Thank you so much!