# Mongo shell query _id between two dates

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find out which objects in a collection were created between two dates, by using their `_id`s:

```
db.landmarks.find( { _id: { $gte:  new Date(2014, 9, 1), $lt:  new Date(2014, 10, 1), } } )
```

This query isn't returning results

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date

Comment: Just in case, you may want to know this: the `ObjectId` generation rule varies between different drivers. Some of them even use pure `string` instead of `ObjectId`.