# Delete mongo recored by the timestamp in its id

Tags: mongodb

This question is mostly popular but with a slight twist; I need to delete few records by when it was created, using its `_id`. I do not have any `date`, `createdAt` fields as [I see](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/) that mongo uses its `_id` for the createdAt timestamp.

How do I delete a recored, say created 30 days ago, using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Stoffo/fd4a0a70be89e8d7ce15)?

```
const date = new Date();
const daysToDeletion = 30;
const deletionDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysToDeletion));

const db = <your-database>

db.messages.remove({_id : {$lt : deletionDate}});
```

> The above returns a `CastError`

What would work, and as Ive said, I do not have a createdAt field:

```
db.messages.remove({createdAt : {$lt : deletionDate}});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I query MongoDB ObjectId by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use mongo shell:

```
db.collection.find({"_id": { "$gt": ObjectId.fromDate(new Date('2017-10-01'))}})
```

Use mongoose:

```
Model.find({ _id: { $gt: mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromTime(new Date('2018-01-01')) } })
```

will find the needed docs.

Answer (score 0):

var id = new ObjectId(  Math.floor(deletionDate .getTime() / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000")

db.messages.remove({createdAt : {$lt : id}});

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the timestamp from the object _id. So you could do something like:-

```
db.messages.find({}).forEach(function(rec) {
    var recDate = rec._id.getTimestamp();
    // Then here cast your deletionDate and recDate to preferred string format, e.g:-
    var recDateString = recDate.getMonth()+1+'-'+recDate.getDate()+'-'+recDate.getFullYear();
    var deletionDateString = deletionDate.getMonth()+1+'-'+deletionDate.getDate()+'-'+deletionDate.getFullYear();

    if (deletionDateString == recDateString ){
        db.messages.remove({_id:rec._id});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.test.deleteMany({"createdAt":{$lte:ISODate("2024-10-19")}})
```

Comment: What does this do? Why do you prefer it over the existing answers? Please [edit] your answer to provide clarification.