# How to get all documents which are created in last three months in mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I want to find all the documents with in collection that got created in last three months (within 3 months only and not older ones).

Sample document :

Cause i thought it would be more reliable.But if you feel that's it's safe you can guide me using `ce` field of document too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can refer to [this existing question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date)!

Comment: it was also very helpful...both solutions are perfect..thanks @saha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question corectly then your chosen comparison field (`ce`) contains the number of **seconds** since the epoch. If so, then you cannot directly compare that with a Javascript `Date` value.

Instead, you'll have to convert the Javascript `Date` object's `time` value to a number of seconds and then compare against that value.

For example:

```
var threeMonthsAgo = new Date();
threeMonthsAgo.setMonth(threeMonthsAgo.getMonth() - 3);
var threeMonthsAgoInSeconds = threeMonthsAgo.getTime() / 1000
db.collection.find({ 
    ce: { $gte: threeMonthsAgoInSeconds } 
})
```

This conversion of millis to seconds is subject to some inaccuracy and if this inaccuracy is unacceptable then I think the solution is to store `ce` as the number of **milliseconds** since the epoch.

If `ce` stored the number of millis then it could be directly compared with the value of the calculated "3 months ago" Javascript date.

However, the above example does **not** require you to convert `ce` into millis. All I'm saying is that comparing a seconds value with a calculated value which is derived from millis introduces some minimal potential for inaccuracy. It's possible that this won't matter in your use case but if it does then the only way to resolve it is to compare like with like i.e. millis against millis.

Comment: thanks mate but problem is that i do have a field to store creation timestamp and it's stored as timstamp like 1523154556, note that it have 10 digits (meaning seconds).

Comment: sorry it's not working , it's giving me empty results.

Comment: Can you update your question to _show_ us an example document? The key parts of interest are (1) the name of your 'creation timestamp' field and (2) how that field is populated.

Comment: My goal is to give preference to my own creation field : ce

Comment: thanks mate but since the collection is humungous (50 million records), i am not at the liberty to convert the ce field into millis, and since the inaccuracy here is completely unacceptable cause it's related with some revenue...is there any workaround you can think of

Comment: I have updated the answer to make clear that I am not saying that you must convert `ce` into millis.