# Getting currentdate in mongodb through JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb

I am writing a process that will run every 1 hour and connect to a mongodb collection. The document in CollectionA has a timestamp key associated. The process then has to search all the new documents inserted in another collection Collection B after the timestamp we got before.

Collection A-(has only 1 documnet which saves the timestamp)
_id:Properties
Timestamp:ISODate("2019-02-13T06:44:45.387Z")

Collection B-(has multiple documents which get updates all thee time)
But it does not have timestamp field.

I have to pick 'Timestamp' from collection A and retrieve all those documents from Collection B that are added after that timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. find last timestamp from collectionA
2. popping timestamp into a fakeObjectId
3. query collectionB with `{ _id: { $gt: fakeObjectId} }`

This idea comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8753670/5142886), the objectId contains document created time, so we can pop a fake objectId as query filter.

Demo code below:

```
public class MongoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient client = MongoClients.create();
        MongoDatabase testDb = client.getDatabase("test");
        MongoCollection<Document> collectionA = testDb.getCollection("test");
        MongoCollection<Document> collectionB = testDb.getCollection("runoob");

        Document first = collectionA.find().first();
        Date lastOptTime = first.getDate("lastOptTime");

        ObjectId fakeObjectId = objectIdFromDate(lastOptTime);

        FindIterable<Document> documents =
                collectionB.find(Filters.gte("_id", fakeObjectId));
        for (Document document : documents) {
            System.out.println(document);
        }
    }

    public static ObjectId objectIdFromDate(Date date) {
        long second = date.getTime() / 1000;
        return new ObjectId(String.format("%02x", second) + "0000000000000000");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, `collectionB.find(Filters.gte("_id", fakeObjectId));` line gives me error saying _"The method find(DBObject) in the type DBCollection is not applicable for the arguments (Bson)"_

Comment: @VishalRoy which version of mongo client do you use? Mine is mongodb-driver-sync 3.10.1 . Maybe older version has different api.

Comment: i am using mongo-java-driver-3.8.2

Comment: @VishalRoy  mongo-java-driver-3.8.2 also works for me.

Comment: yeah it is working for me now. I was using deprecated db instead of MongoDatabase. However my CollectionA has multiple documents . How can i search with a condition like where _id:"abc"?

Comment: @VishalRoy I thought you just need to `find()` the last timestamp from collectionA with some filters, I don't know how to filter according to your description.

Comment: okay understood. Just one last thing, what is the logic behind objectIdFromDate method

Comment: @VishalRoy Because mongo generate objectId by:  hex("timestamp") + randomValue1 + randomValue2 + counter + sth,  so we can fake a objectId from date, and use this fakeObjectId to filter by create date. see the link i paste above.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your data with `findByCreatedAtGreaterThan(LocalDateTime oneHourLessFromNow )` where time is one hour less than now.

You can calculate the one hour less time with following code.

```
LocalDateTime oneHourLessFromNow = LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(1);
```