# Query to get data from mongodb using ObjectId ("xxxxxxxxx").GetTimestamp()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I am starting in the world of **mongodb**.

I have the following question:

I want to find the items that were posted from date x. In the records I have no date but I can get it from this statement:

`ObjectId ("5ffdc390fdd1596ca5870bec"). GetTimestamp ()`

whose result is: `ISODate ("2021-01-12T15: 43: 12Z")`

How could I create a query that returns all the records that were created from a given date, for example from 2021-01-12?
Thank you very much.!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I query MongoDB ObjectId by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date)

Comment: No, I'm working only with mongodb and not from an app.I need only a mongodb query

Comment: I've found an alternative solution that is comparing with an oid created with a defined date to compare
db.getCollection("files").find({"_id" : { $lte :ObjectId("6018c0300000000000000000") }}) 
It works but it's not the deffinitive solution

Answer (score 2):

The mongo Shell is an interactive JavaScript interface to MongoDB, so the solution by **[Leftium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8753670/4980141)** should work.

```
function objectIdWithTimestamp(timestamp) {
    /* Convert string date to Date object (otherwise assume timestamp is a date) */
    if (typeof(timestamp) == 'string') {
        timestamp = new Date(timestamp);
    }

    /* Convert date object to hex seconds since Unix epoch */
    var hexSeconds = Math.floor(timestamp/1000).toString(16);

    /* Create an ObjectId with that hex timestamp */
    var constructedObjectId = new ObjectId(hexSeconds + "0000000000000000");

    return constructedObjectId
}


/* Find all documents created between Jan 12th, 2021 and Jan 13th, 2021 */
db.mycollection.find({ _id: { $gt: objectIdWithTimestamp('2021/01/12'), $lt: objectIdWithTimestamp('2021/01/13')  } });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query it directly:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: { 
     $gte: [ {$toDate: "$_id"}, ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00Z") ] }
  }
)
```

Usually I prefer the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library, could be this for example:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: { 
     $gte: [ {$toDate: "$_id"}, moment().startOf('day').subtract(3, 'days').toDate() ] }
  }
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me:
db.fs.files.find({_id: {$lte: ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00+01:00")}}) 
--Fetched 0 record(s) in 27ms
But there are many records that would be showed:
db.getCollection("fs.files").count({"_id" : { $lte :ObjectId("6018c0300000000000000000")}})
--631
ObjectId("6018c0300000000000000000").getTimestamp()
---ISODate("2021-02-02T03:00:00Z")

Comment: Update my answer